# Retrieve the day name from the day of the week number in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string representation of day of the week (i.e 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and 7) as a field in a table. From these I want to output name of day (as Monday, Tuesday etc) using oracle SQL without using a case statement. Anyone with an idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think a `case` might be the simplest solution:

```
select (case dow when '1' then 'Monday' when '2' then 'Tuesday' when '3' then 'Wednesday'
                 when '4' then 'Thursday' when '5' then 'Friday' when '6' then 'Saturday'
                 when '7' then 'Sunday'
        end)
```

This may not be quite as fancy as converting to dates, but you can get exactly the string that you want without fiddling with date arithmetic.

If you want date arithmetic, then use `trunc()`:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'IW') + dow - 1, 'Dy')
```

Note:  This produces day abbreviations.  Use `'Day'` if you want the full week day name.

This truncates the current date to the beginning of the ISO week, which starts on a Monday.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following:

```
WITH day_map AS (SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL, 'FMD') id
                      , TO_CHAR(SYSDATE+LEVEL, 'FMDay') name
                   FROM dual
                CONNECT BY LEVEL < 8)
SELECT m.NAME
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE> t
  LEFT JOIN day_map m 
    ON m.id = t.<day_of_week>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because 20190106 is sunday, you could use this, replace 20190106 by any other sunday:

But IMO you should better write a function using `CASE` and return your result for better performance

```
WITH table_name AS
(
    SELECT '1' AS c1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '2' AS c1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '3' AS c1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '6' AS c1 FROM dual 
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('20190106', 'YYYYMMDD') + c1, 'Day') 
FROM table_name;
```